fzf: make sort by relevance the default
In the FZF README, under the section for command line history, it states:
CTRL-R - Paste the selected command from history onto the command-line

If you want to see the commands in chronological order, press CTRL-R again which toggles sorting by relevance

I find that I almost always get the best results when toggling that.
How can I configure it to be on by default for CTRL-R?

Put export FZF_CTRL_R_OPTS="--tiebreak=index" in your shell startup.
